# React Native ScrollView not scrolling in the most basic format ^^

Tags: react-native, scrollview

This is the first using ScrollView and after not managing to get it working on screen where I needed to I made new component just to test it out and what happens is when I refresh it it shows scroll bar on the side for a split second and the 'length' looks appropriate for amount of lines I added but I can't scroll it. This is what my test looks like ^^ What am I doing wrong? Would appreciate the help

```
        <View  style={{flex: 1}}>
            <ScrollView>
                <Text style={{paddingVertical: 30, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginVertical: 10}}>hello</Text>
                <Text style={{paddingVertical: 30, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginVertical: 10}}>hello</Text>
                <Text style={{paddingVertical: 30, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginVertical: 10}}>hello</Text>
                <Text style={{paddingVertical: 30, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginVertical: 10}}>hello</Text>
                <Text style={{paddingVertical: 30, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginVertical: 10}}>hello</Text>
                <Text style={{paddingVertical: 30, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginVertical: 10}}>hello</Text>
                <Text style={{paddingVertical: 30, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginVertical: 10}}>hello</Text>
                <Text style={{paddingVertical: 30, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginVertical: 10}}>hello</Text>
                <Text style={{paddingVertical: 30, backgroundColor: 'orange', marginVertical: 10}}>hello</Text>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
        
    )
```

Comment: *Update* Try `<ScrollView style={{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1}} >`

Comment: Cool. Glad to know!✨